# How to keep both flows using Lookup object in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, bids

Have a problem into a Data flow task, in SSIS.

In my current flow, I want to add some additional data, using a lookup object. If there is a match then to add the data based on the settings from the Lookup object and for no match to keep the process unchanged.

I set my lookup object to redirect the not matching records to No Match output and linked it to the existing flow (as I don't want to change the existing records, just to enhance with some additional data), but I don't know how link the Match output to the same flow.

If I was to use a TSql statement I've just used left join, but I just can't figure what other objects from SSIS to use, in order to have the existing flow unchanged, just to enhance it, when there's a match, with the new data.

Comment: What would happen, for my current flow, if I set my setting for the Lookup object to just ignore the records with no match? Will the records still go through the LookUp object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without using of lookup redirect output.

Just configure Lookup to ignore `No Match` error so the output value will be set to `Null` for non matched value.

After doing this, add a `Multicast` Component after the Lookup , so you have multiplied your output then add a `Conditional Split` in one of The `MultiCast` outputs and filter Rows where `ISNULL([YourColumn]) == True` *(You will get only No Match Rows in one output and all rows in the other)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Merge join](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-merge-join-transformation/%20%22Merge%20join) component for that.

You need to sort your data (can be done with a `sort component`) first. After that, just connect the two components with the `Merge join component`.

In the `merge join`, you can select which kind of join you want (check the link above for more about that). Works just like a T-SQL statement